# How would I append a tuple to a list with a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, tuples

I'm trying to append a tuple to a list with a loop but can't seem to figure it out. I feel that I am very close as i'm getting an index error - list index out of range.

I've tried adding or subtracting in the WordListToTuple function and the contained loop, but still nothing, google/youtube seem to be no help either.

Here's the code:

```
AcronymList = []
DefinitionList = []
ListTuple = []


def openFile(filename, list):
    Text_File = open(filename, 'r+') #Open and store text file as list
    global TextFileLineCount
    TextFileLineCount = Text_File.readlines()#Count the lines in the file
    for line in TextFileLineCount:
        list.append(line.strip())  # Removes unneccessary garbage
    Text_File.close()
    #print(list)

def WordListToTuple():
    count = 0
    for count in range(len(TextFileLineCount)):
        ListTuple[count].append(tuple((AcronymList), (1)))


getWordListFileName = input("Enter the filename and extension for the word list:  ")
openFile(getWordListFileName, AcronymList)
WordListToTuple()
```

Comment: You don't need a count.  Python will count for you.  Just do `ListTuple.append((AcronymList,1))`.  You also don't need the `tuple` call.  Just the parens are enough.  But, since you're appending the same thing over and over, you can replace the loop with `ListTuple = [(AcronymList,1)] * len(TextFileLineCount)`.

Comment: I see parentheses around a primary: e.g. `(1)`. This does not have any effect. If you want a tuple containing just one item, use a comma at the end of the items:  `(AcronymList,)`, `(1,)`.

Comment: (Why `'r+'` instead of `'r'`?)

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you want `list_tuple` to contain one tuple `(item, 1)` for every item in `acronym_list`, just tell Python:

```
list_tuple = [ (item, 1) for item in acronym_list ]
```

Comment: (This does not *really* use/contain a *loop*.)

Answer (score 0):

just do `ListTuple.append(tuple(AcronymList, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
list = []
tup = (1,2,3,4,5)
for i in tup:
          list.append(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].